# xCode - How to stop one action when another occurs

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, audio

I have an app that speaks words. However, when word B is pressed, I want to stop word A. Is there a way to do that? This is my code for speaking the words:

```
-(IBAction)sayIt:(id)sender
{
//NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
FlashCardsAppDelegate *mainDelegate = (FlashCardsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
soundFileURLRef= CFBundleCopyResourceURL (mainBundle, (CFStringRef)[mainDelegate soundFile], CFSTR("caf"), NULL);   
UInt32 soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use AVAudioPlayer as a class member,
call player.stop and player.play to stop and start audio.
if you need to change the sound after stopping the player use InitWithData

Comment: Hi Gal.. this could be just the thing.. I'm reading the documentation on AVAudioPlayer.. I remember trying this in another app and having some difficulties - maybe latency..

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the docs, it does not look like you can stop it playing the alert until its complete.

But you can use a callback to tell when it has finished playing to avoid playing two sounds.
Look at:

**AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion**

> Discussion
>   Because a system sound may play for several seconds, you might want to know when it has finished playing. For example, you may want to wait until a system sound has finished playing before you play another sound.

and

**AudioServicesSystemSoundCompletionProc**

> Discussion
>   Because a system sound may play for up to 30 seconds, the AudioServicesPlaySystemSound function executes asynchronously (that is, it returns immediately). This callback gets invoked when a specified system sound has finished playing. You can use this callback, for example, to help you avoid playing a second sound while a first sound is still playing.